# Drawing on a rendered pdf - Swing

Tags: java, swing, pdf, itext, jpedal

After being extremely annoyed at the lack of free software to draw directly onto pdfs, I've decided to write it myself.

I aim to achieve this by having some sort of canvas widget in a GUI with the contents of a pdf displayed underneath it, and record (and render) everything drawn onto the screen and when saving the file, save everything drawn as a .png (with a transparent background) and overlay it onto the .pdf.

I've already written the stuff for overlaying the pdf (using iText), but am not sure how to approach the GUI stuff. How should I proceed about rendering the pdf?
I've seen an approach involving converting a page of the .pdf into an image (PDF-renderer) and chucking that in Swing, but I imagine this will have resolution issues (zooming).

Another idea I've had is to render the .pdf in a swing element using the Viewer widget from JPedal, but I'm not sure how I'd set up the canvas.

So, how should I approach this?
What should the general structure of my interface?
I've not tried either of these options (I'm still investigating their library interfaces). I wanted to seek advice early (since it's about the very base structure of the program).

Comment: the lack of free software to draw directly onto pdfs, my shot to the dark == draw to the JLayer(JXLayer for Java6) or GlassPane, then create BufferedImage from JFrame.getRootPane/ContentPane or to use [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) by @camickr directly

Comment: GlassPane sounds good (I can chuck it atop Viwewer). Any advice on the actual translating of mouse clicks/drag into a drawing on GlassPane?

Comment: GlassPane (any JComponent must be placed onto, then) by default to consume() all MouseEvents, KeyEvents must be (added KeyListener to any JComponent placed onto) consume() if needed

Comment: use JLayer, better, new API, new methods and more managable

Comment: JLayer does look good. Hmm, I've had a wrong impression about the viewer widget; it allows u to embed their pdf application into a swing program (along with all the menu bars and what not) which I do not desire. How should I go about rendering the pdf? (do the image thing?)

Comment: I haven't any idea about, but this question is weekly asked in Swing rellated questions

Comment: @AntiEarth: the glass pane tutorial example illustrates delegation for mouse events.

Comment: Why do you draw on a bitmap? Vector graphics (paths in PDF) would bee much more natural...

Comment: @mKorbel these comments were helpful; you should consider making them an answer c:

Answer (score 0):

Rendering PDFs is incredibly complicated. We develop ABCpdf and I would guess we have perhaps forty man years of investment just in the rendering side.

So if you want to do this you should start by limiting what you need to do. Either you need to ensure that your PDFs come from a uniform source that uses a restricted set of functionality, or you need to accept that many of your PDFs will not render correctly.

Next you need to decompress the page content stream(s) then break it into PDF operators. Then create a System.Drawing.Bitmap or similar and use each of the PDF drawing operators to draw on that drawing surface. You will find full details of the operators in the PDF Spec which is available on the Adobe web site.

Provided your PDF source is consistent, simple and uniform you will probably be able to get something sensible out within a few weeks. Happy coding :-)